# Как заставить выполнять SSI команды на локальном сервере?

Tags: ssi, сервер

Итак дали мне на работе проект (сайт), чтобы я его поставил на локальный сервер для разработки. Сделал все правильно, все залилось но есть один минус. В коде используется SSI для подгрузки некоторых блоков причем используется так:

```
<!--# include virtual="/xxx/x/banners/getBannersRight.php" -->
```

Синтаксис SSI. насколько мне известно, не разрешает ставить пробел между `#` и `include` но на боевом сервере все работает! А на моем локальном естественно нет ([`an error occurred while processing this directive`]). Полазил в настройках и не нашел как сделать так, чтобы у меня на локальном сервере это завелось. Вопрос такой: как мне заставить выполнять такие SSI команды на моем локальном сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ оказался прост! ставим nginx врубаем ssi в nginx радуемся!